# Prevent docker container from accessing localhost

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, docker

I noticed that I can access the host from a docker container by using the `docker0` gateway address. For security reasons I want to block / limit this access.

I already used the following iptables rule to prevent the container from accessing my local network:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Running `curl 192.168.1.1` inside the container results in a timeout (as expected).

I want to achieve the same when accessing my host system using the docker default gateway, i.e. `curl 172.17.0.1` should also result in a time out.

Furthermore I want to block all ports except one. On my host system runs a mysql server (port 3306) which should be accessible by all containers.

Comment: I might be missing something, but can't you just add a modification of your INPUT rule e.g. `iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -s 172...\PREFIX -j DROP`, plus insert a rule that allows port 3306?

Comment: @berndbausch - Post an answer. Insert an allow rule for port 3306 followed by a deny rule. The trick with this question is what rules already exist and where should the rules be inserted at.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the suggestion, but I am just being too lazy to hammer it out. OP will know what to do.

Comment: @berndbausch I've tried this command, however docker seems to ignore it. It seems like the requests are not routed through the docker0 interface..?

Comment: @random314 - check to see if you have other rules that allow the network traffic. A matching allow stops rule processing so a later deny rule is not evaluated.